# issue in 'when in', converting SQL query to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a SQL query I am trying to convert to MYSQL
I like the 'when...in' and i do not find a way to adapt it to mysql...

```
SELECT SUM
    (
    CASE

            WHEN tran_type IN (
                'GAME_BET',
                'GAME_WIN',
                'ROLLBACK',
                'CASH_OUT',
                'STAKE_DEC',
                'REFUND' 
                ) THEN
                ( amount_real ) 
                WHEN tran_type IN ( 'BONUS_REL' ) THEN
                (amount_released_bonus ) 
            END 
            ) 
    FROM
    datafeed
```

Comment: This is standard SQL and should work in any database.  You might be having a problem with the space after the `sum`.

Comment: I agree, the problem is the whitespace after `SUM`. MySQL only recognizes calls to the built-in function if it's written as `SUM(` with no space before `(`.

Comment: thanks, it solved my issue ;)